# Mysql Password Expired , Using Homestead Virtualbox

Tags: mysql, homestead

I keep getting this message on my larval application

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 119:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1862] Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords.
```

I've tried reseting password like so :

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('secret');
```

i get a response

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

but when still get error in my view, I tried connecting to db using sequel pro, and got the same error

```
MySQL said: Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords.
```

not sure what else i can do, I tried vagrant provision after the reset, and still get same error

Comment: Im getting the same error as well. Iv'e tried making a homestead user and changing the password but nothing seems to work. Even logging into mamp and doing it manually seems fatal as well. I hopw someone knows something

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I have solved it modifying homestead files.
In vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/create-mysql.sh

```
mysql -uhomestead -psecret -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$DB\` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci";
```

This is the line that gives me the problem. Before this line i reset the password with --connect-expired-password option. I have to reset the laravel bd user password too. Supposing that laravel bd user is root and password is secret:

```
mysql -uhomestead -psecret -e "SET PASSWORD  = PASSWORD('secret')" --connect-expired-password;
mysql -uroot -psecret -e "SET PASSWORD  = PASSWORD('secret')" --connect-expired-password;
mysql -uhomestead -psecret -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$DB\` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci";
```

Works for me.

Comment: I would propose a pull request upstream or creating a fork of homestead with this fix in it. Modifying *any* code in your vendor folder isn't good practice because it'll be overwritten by any update that comes after it by date. It also means you aren't sharing the fix so other developers on your team would have to integrate the same change when it's much easier to just pull your fork or the updated package.